# How can I use JDT's Add New Class Wizard's Add Interface Feature?

Tags: java, plugins, code-generation, wizard, eclipse-jdt

I have an interface like ;

```
interface Animal {
   public void eat();
   public void travel();
}
```

I want to generate new class which implements this interface like;

```
public class Mammal implements Animal {
   public void eat() {
        //...
   }
   public void travel() {
        //..
   } 
}
```

This process is totally same with right click > new > class > name it > add interface > press ok. To use this feature, I can use JDT's New Java Class Wizard's Add Interface feature. However,

1) How can I use this Add Interface Feature via JDT ?

2) I do not want to show any ui to user. Is it possible ?

3(optional)) Do you have any suggestion about to generate this .java file instead of using JDT's Wizard ? I do not want to use StringBuilder to create this new .java file because of lack of maintaning.

Thanks all.

Comment: Well the first thing to do is understand the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html#using-the-ast) which JDT uses for everything like this.